# java.awt seems to be empty

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm trying to import the class RenderingHints like so:

```
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
```

but java.awt seems to be completely empty of any classes at all so I'm getting a "cannot be resolved" error. My understanding is that java.awt package is included with the JDK. I'm up to date with that (version 1.7) - so what could be causing the issue?

I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: please post the error you're getting

Comment: Have you modified your classpath?

Comment: I'm just getting a "The import java.awt.RenderingHints cannot be resolved" error in Eclipse. It's like the awt package is completely empty - when I type the dot after java.awt, nothing comes up in the auto complete.

Comment: atk - you're a genius. Yes I'd fiddled around with the classpath and must've removed it by accident. If you answer I'll mark it right.